# Websites hosted on Amazon S3 loading very slowly

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I have an application which is a static website builder.Users can create their websites and publish them to their custom domains.I am using Amazon S3 to host these sites and a proxy server **nginx** to route the requests to the S3 bucket hosting sites.
      I am facing a load time issue.As S3 specifically is not associated with any region and the content being entirely HTML there shouldn't ideally be any delay.I have a few css and js files which are not too heavy.

What can be the optimization techniques for better performance? eg: Will setting headers ? or Leverage caching help? I have added an image of pingdom analysis for reference.

Also i cannot use cloudfront as when the user updates an image the edge locations have a delay of few minutes before the new image is reflected.It is not instant update,hence restricting the use for me. Any suggestions on improving it?

[image]

Comment: the way to get around the "updated image" problem is to use a new filename for each modification to an image. It's a very common pattern.

Comment: @tedder42 I need to keep the filenames intact for the user as I also allow them to use them for sharing,where names have to be relevant and as user specified.

Comment: I believe even if the file is new,in my case it showed up the old image itself,so do I need to invalidate individual objects? For example: If I replace **images/myimage.jpg** with **images/yourimage.jpg**,do I need to invalidate `myimage.jpg` to remove it from edge locations? Going through the docs also says invalidation will be charged and can I do it on the fly or only via aws console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 HTTPS access from a different region is extremely slow especially TLS handshake. To solve the problem we invented Nginx S3 proxy which can be find over the web. S3 is the best as origin source but not as a transport endpoint.

By the way try to avoid your "folder" as a subdomain but specify only S3 regional(!) endpoint URL instead with the long version of endpoint [URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html), never use https://s3.amazonaws.com

One the good example that reduces number of DNS calls is the following below:

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/folder/file.jpg

Comment: We do use region specific names for images and files. If you see our region is Singapore and in the snapshot I have added the URL is s3-ap-southeast and so on. We cannot avoid using folders as subdomain as that's our use case, hosting static websites.

Comment: Right, sounds good. Let me clarify few things first. Do you have an Nginx to proxy the S3 request through? It that case S3 endpoint is hidden and not used directly.

Comment: Yes we have a nginx server for proxying requests,but it proxies only for the domain name mapped with the S3 folder whose name is same as the website or domain.So when user hits a domain name it goes to nginx,picks up the route and hits the folder in bucket.You are right its hidden!! So whats yor suggestion?

Comment: Do you use http between EC2 (same region) and S3 bucket, not https? Have you tried http keep alive and nginx resolver cache?

Comment: we use `https` and I have no idea about nginx resolver cache and haven't tried it.How would it help and can you help me by directing to document or sharing the details on this?

Comment: HTTPS between EC2 and S3 within the same region is not required especially if you have static public content. SSL handshake is the main bottlenect in that case. https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files

Comment: Nice article,I will try to test it by implementing and get back with results.One more query was just by changing `https` to `http` will it reduce the load considerably or it will not be a big change in download time?

Comment: SSL/TLS handshake is very slow on AWS S3 endpoints and it's problematic to cache the session key. So yes, plain HTTP makes a difference

Comment: I even advice you to use Nginx cache to make O(1) not O(N) requests to S3.

Comment: yes sure,I hope I am able to implement the caching! Thank you very much for the inputs! (Y)

Comment: Thank you Sir,followed you on github for future updates.Great help to me!

Answer (score 1):

Your S3 buckets **are** associated with a specific region that you can choose when you create them. They are not geographically distributed. Please see AWS doc about S3 regions: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

As we can see in your screenshot, it looks like your bucket is located in Singapore (ap-southeast-1).

Are your clients located in Asia? If they are not, you should try to create buckets nearer, in order to reduce data access latency.

About cloudfront, it should be possible to use it if you [invalide your objects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html), or just use new filenames for each modification, as tedder42 suggested.

Comment: As important as the client location, of course, is the proximity of the nginx proxy to both the S3 bucket's region (location constraint) and to the users, since it sounds like requests are passing through that proxy (which is, incidentally, a valid configuration with some very useful advantages).

Comment: Yes my clients are from Asia,specifically India. @Michael-sqlbot the nginx proxy server is also located in the same region Singapore. Also,currently there is not much traffic as the application is in private Beta.One more update is it is a t1.micro instance for nginx,so is it that causing the problem? And about invalidating,I actually need to keep the names intact as the same files are used for sharing.

Comment: You should definitely move up to a t2.micro.  It is a much faster machine with a very different (and more generous) throttling model, at a lower price per hour.  The unknown variable that you need to study is where the lag occurs?  Browser to proxy or proxy to S3?  I use a HAProxy for a similar application, which gives me very fine-grained timers in the log, for several segments of the request handling process; hopefully nginx can provide you with something similar.  You also probably want keepalives enabled, and to disable nginx buffering but I am not an expert on nginx config.

Comment: Thank you Michael-sqlbot I will try finding a way to debug the request.Thanks for the insight.                                                        @Pierre-Jean Bergeron Can you update me on invalidating?Can I do it on the fly when user uploads the image? or I have to do it using the AWS console?